# Pagination Math Issue

Tags: c#, algorithm, visual-studio, math, pagination

I have a pagination issue :

I have a large number of pages as results in my table ~50.000 pages and my pagination logic is something like : 
**1** 2 3 ...50000
I would like to do something like :

**1** 2 3 10 100 500 1000 5000 10000 50000

And when i click for example 1111 :

1 1109 1110 **1111** 1112 1113 1114 1120 1200 1700 2200 3000 8000 10000 50000

so far I;ve tried something like this :

```
int Max_count = (int)Math.Floor(Math.Log10(totalPages) + 1);
                    for (int index = start; index <= end; index++)
                    {
                        if (index == pageNumber)
                        {
                            header.Items.Add(new PagingHeaderModelItem(PageHeaderItemType.CurrentPage, pageNumber));
                        }
                        else if (index == start)
                        {
                            header.Items.Add(new PagingHeaderModelItem(PageHeaderItemType.StartPage, 0));
                        }
                        else if (index == end)
                        {
                            header.Items.Add(new PagingHeaderModelItem(PageHeaderItemType.EndPage, totalPages - 1));
                        }
                        else if ((index == start + 1) && (index > 1))
                        {
                            header.Items.Add(new PagingHeaderModelItem(PageHeaderItemType.MorePages, -1));
                        }
                        else if ((index == end - 1) && (index < totalPages - 2))
                        {
                            header.Items.Add(new PagingHeaderModelItem(PageHeaderItemType.MorePages, -1));
                        }
                        else if ((index > 100) && (index > totalPages / 2))
                        {
                            header.Items.Add(new PagingHeaderModelItem(PageHeaderItemType.SimplePage, index));
                        }
                        else if ((pageNumber + 2 > index) && index + 10 < totalPages && !isSecond)
                        {
                            for (int temp = 1; temp < Max_count; temp++)
                            {
                                int power_var = (int)Math.Pow(10, temp);
                                int power_var_prev = (int)Math.Pow(10, temp - 1);
                                if ((pageNumber > power_var) || pageNumber < 10)
                                {
                                    header.Items.Add(new PagingHeaderModelItem(PageHeaderItemType.SimplePage, power_var - 1));
                                    header.Items.Add(new PagingHeaderModelItem(PageHeaderItemType.SimplePage, power_var - 1 + power_var_prev));

                                    temp++;
                                }
                            }
                            isSecond = true;
                        }
                          else if (index - start < 3)
                        {
                            header.Items.Add(new PagingHeaderModelItem(PageHeaderItemType.SimplePage, index));
                        }
```

But i Feel like I'm not close to this at all. I'm not asking for a solution more of a hint or a formula I could use to do this by myself

**LATER EDIT**

The pattern should be like :

```
n-3,                                  // 1         //1 
n-2,                                  // 2         //1109       
n-1,                                  // 3         //1110
**n**,                                // **4**     //1111
n+1,                                  //5          //1112
n+2,                                  //6          //1113
n+3,                                  //7          //1114
Math.Floor((index + 10)) / 10) * 10, //10          //1120
Math.Floor((index + 10)) / 10) * 10 +50, //60      //1170
Math.Floor((index + 100)) / 100) * 100, //100      //1200
Math.Floor((index + 100)) / 100) * 100+500,//600   //1700
Math.Floor((index + 1000)) / 1000) * 1000,//1000   //2000
Math.Floor((index + 1000)) / 1000) * 1000+5000,//6000/7000
```

....

Comment: The samples you've provided are inconsistent between themselves - in first example there's 5000 after 1000, but in the latter case it's 8000 after 3000. Any chance you could describe the numbers you're trying to achieve?

Comment: *Edited ... hope it is more clear now

Comment: Can you also expand on the desired output for 1111, like you did for 4? Surely you don't want the first value to be 10000 or 5000 (which it would be based on 4's desired output).

Comment: Yes my bad ... first item will always be 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Here's some code to print the desired values:**

(it does print 1108 as well, but that should be easy enough to work around)

(changed +50, +500, etc. to +40, +400, etc. because I prefer that)

```
int min = 1, max = 50000;

if (val-3 > min)
   Console.WriteLine(min);

for (int i = Math.Max(min, val-3); i <= Math.Min(max, val+3); i++)
   Console.WriteLine(i);

int last = -1;
for (int i = 10; ; i *= 10)
{
   int next = (val+3 + i) / i * i;
   if (next > max)
      break;
   // prevent printing something like 90, 130, 100, 500 (100 won't print)
   if (next > last)
      Console.WriteLine(next);
   next += 4*i;
   if (next > max)
      break;
   Console.WriteLine(next);
   last = next;
}
```

[Live demo](https://ideone.com/r0A3Hy).

If you want to print it from the value to the minimum as well, it could be a simple case of copying the for-loop and inverting the values: (it will print the values from the largest, changing this will require a stack data structure)

```
for (int i = 10; ; i *= 10)
{
   int next = (val-3 - i) / i * i;
   if (next < min)
      break;
   if (next < last)
      Console.WriteLine(next);
   next -= 4*i;
   if (next < min)
      break;
   Console.WriteLine(next);
   last = next;
}
if (last != min)
   Console.WriteLine(min);
```

**Here's another idea:**

Taking `1111` in `1..50000` as an example.

Take the 2 values before and the 2 values after - `1109, 1110, 1111, 1112, 1113`.

Let's say we want an exponential growth towards the target, with 5 points in between.

The range of values upwards would be `50000 - 1113 = 48887` (starting from biggest value above).

Then we want to find `x` such that `(5x)^2 = 48887`. This is fairly easy to calculate, just square root 48887 and divide by 5 - `sqrt(48887) / 5 = 44.22`

Then the values would be:

```
1113 + (1 * 44.22) ^ 2 = 3068
1113 + (2 * 44.22) ^ 2 = 8934
1113 + (3 * 44.22) ^ 2 = 18712
1113 + (4 * 44.22) ^ 2 = 32400
1113 + (5 * 44.22) ^ 2 = 50000
```

Similarly for downwards.

You can probably base the number of values in between on how far the target is, if you wish.

If you'd prefer more round numbers, I'd have to think about that a bit more.

Comment: thanks this helps greatly. I will try and implement it. Although this is not exactly my particular question I will prolly choose this cause it would fit my project better